# Easily change build configurations (DEBUG <-> RELEASE) in all projects in a workspace in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have an Eclipse workspace comprising of many CDT type projects. Currently to switch between DEBUG and RELEASE build configurations, I have to manually go to each project and set the configuration I want as 'active' and also ensure they are all set to the same configuration. This is a pain!

What is the best way to set all projects in a workspace to DEBUG / RELEASE at the same time?

NOTE: I don't have vanilla Eclipse. Our Eclipse-based IDE from Mentor Graphics is called Sourcery CodeBench IDE. (Eclipse Platform Version: 4.5.2 -- so maybe MARS?)